# Fancybox v3 ignores data-options

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I use Fandybox v3. Unfortunately there is a problem with usage of data-options.

This is my Code:

```
<a data-fancybox data-options='{"caption": "My caption", "src": "iframe.html", "css": {"maxWidth": "500", "width": "500", "maxHeight": "300", "height": "300"}}' href="javascript:;" title="abc">
```

No matter what I did, the cation shown below the iframe is always "abc" instead of "My caption" and the settings für width and height are also ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in fancyBox3, if you want to set the caption set a value to data-caption attribute :

```
<a data-fancybox data-caption="My caption" href="javascript:;">
    Open external page using iframe
</a>
```

The problem is near these lines :

```
// Caption is a "special" option, it can be passed as a method
if ( $.type( obj.opts.caption ) === 'function' ) {
     obj.opts.caption = obj.opts.caption.apply( item, [ self, obj ] );

} else if ( 'caption' in data ) {
    obj.opts.caption = data.caption;

} else if ( opts.$orig ) {
   obj.opts.caption = $item.attr( 'title' );
}
```

I'm investigating why this happens.

**EDIT :**

I fixed the fancybox caption issue there (maybe you should put an issue on github for this):

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/g675hag6/